# when i add time interval to nsdate it won't added

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

when i add time interval to nsdate it won't added

```
     dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ss"];
    dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:app.currentDate];//app.currentDate means nsdate
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString); 
    [defaults  setObject:dateString  forKey:@"Default_second"]; 
    NSTimeInterval timeInter = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Default_second"]doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%f--",timeInter);
    [app.currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-timeInter];
```

Comment: Add a `NSLog(@"%@",app.currentDate);` printout before and after the `dateByAddingTimeInterval` invocation. Paste the results.

Comment: This is not a question. What is the problem? What are you expecting to see? What do you actually see? What, indeed, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set app.currentDate like:

```
[app setCurrentDate: [app.currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-timeInter]];
```